# How to determine the minimum number of edges to form a rigid structure in ${\mathbb R}^d$ ($d = 2,3$)?

Tags: linear-algebra, rigid-analytic-spaces

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be $n$ points in ${\mathbb R}^d$ ($d = 2,3$). Then, what is the minimum number of edges to form a rigid structure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Laman's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LamansTheorem.html) for $\mathbb{R}^2$.  The case for $\mathbb{R}^3$ is more complicated - see the [double banana](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/A-double-banana-is-a-bar-and-joint-assembly-defined-by-two-bipyramids-joined-by-their_fig1_256605606).

If you want a lower bound, take the number of degrees of freedom of the points and subtract the dimension of the [Euclidean group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_group).  This works because each edge *can* remove one degree of freedom.  However, having this number of edges doesn't guarantee that the structure is rigid.

In $\mathbb{R}^d$, each point has $d$ degrees of freedom, and the Euclidean group has dimension $\frac{d(d+1)}{2}$.  Therefore, the minimum number of edges required is $dn-\frac{d(d+1)}{2}$.  Therefore, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the number of edges required is $2n-3$ and in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the number of edges required is $3n-6$.

This argument requires that nontrivial subgroups of the Euclidean group do not stabilize the set, so we must assume that the vectors between the points span $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and detailed answer! [+1]

Comment: Hmm... It seems that for $d = 3$ and $n = 2$, $3n-6 = 0$ cannot reflect the minimum number of edges.

Comment: In that case, there's a motion that fixes the points - around the axis.  Therefore, the Euclidean motions have fewer degrees of freedom.  You need the vectors between the points to span $\mathbb{R}^d$ for these formulas to apply.

Comment: Thanks a lot! [+1] It seems that spanning vectors in ${\mathbb R}^{d-1}$ is sufficient for applying these formulae :-)

Comment: Note that these conditions are necessary, but not sufficient, even in the spanning case.

Comment: Thanks for your comments :-)